# How can I CONCAT portions of three columns to one new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a new column in my results that is made up on the first 3 characters of "PrimaryName", all of "VendorCity", and the first 5 characters of "VendorZip"

```
SELECT,VendorName
      ,replace(PrimaryVendorLocationName,' ','') as PrimaryName
      ,replace(PrimaryVendorLocationCity,' ','') as VendorCity
      ,replace(PrimaryVendorLocationZipCode,' ','') as VendorZip
FROM [table]
```

As you can see I also need to remove spaces to ensure a cleaner return. I would like to call the new column "NewVendorCode". So a record that originates like this:

> ```
> R A Slack
> Chicago Heights
> 60654-1234
> ```

Will return this:

> ```
> RASChicagoHeights60654
> ```

Comment: sql server management studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following, using `LEFT` ([MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) / [TSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql)):

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    LEFT(REPLACE(PrimaryVendorLocationName, ' ', ''), 3),
    REPLACE(PrimaryVendorLocationCity, ' ', ''),
    LEFT(REPLACE(PrimaryVendorLocationZipCode, ' ', ''), 5)
) FROM table_name
```

... or you can use `SUBSTRING` ([MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) / [TSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql)) (instead of `LEFT`):

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING(REPLACE(PrimaryVendorLocationName, ' ', ''), 1, 3),
    REPLACE(PrimaryVendorLocationCity, ' ', ''),
    SUBSTRING(REPLACE(PrimaryVendorLocationZipCode, ' ', ''), 1, 5)
) FROM table_name
```

**Note:** As you can see the `SELECT` querys work on MySQL and TSQL without change.

> **demo (MySQL):** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wTuKzosFgkEuKXtruCTCxg/0
>   **demo (TSQL):** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dbc98/1/1

Comment: That did it. I was close, but not quite there. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
  SELECT VendorName+
  replace(PrimaryVendorLocationName,' ','') +
  replace(PrimaryVendorLocationCity,' ','') +
  replace(PrimaryVendorLocationZipCode,' ','') as NewVendorCode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT VendorName
  ,PrimaryName
  ,VendorCity
  ,VendorZip
  ,CONCAT(LEFT(PrimaryName,3),VendorCity,LEFT(VendorZip,5)) As NewVendorCode
FROM (
     SELECT VendorName
       ,replace(PrimaryVendorLocationName,' ','') as PrimaryName
       ,replace(PrimaryVendorLocationCity,' ','') as VendorCity
       ,replace(PrimaryVendorLocationZipCode,' ','') as VendorZip
     FROM [table]
)
```